# Android app for multiple screen(Phones and Tablet)

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

I have to develop the attached screen for phones,7'' tablet and 10'' tablet.
[image: Android screen]

Please tell me the following things.

1.what should be size of background image(in pixels) for phone?

2.In which drawable folder i have to keep the background images  for phone?

3.what should be size of background image(in pixels) for 7'' tablet

4.In which drawable folder i have to keep the background image  for 7'' tablet?

5.what should be size of background image(in pixels) for 10'' tablet?

6.In which drawable folder i have to keep the background image(in pixels)  for 7'' tablet?

since there is same layout(final output same) for phone ,7'' tablet and 10'' tablet so i am using the one single layout file(activity_main.xml) which is kept inside layout folder if i also need to make change here then please suggest.

Comment: Check out [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use size qualifiers to support multiple devices

```
For your layouts
For phone layout-sw320dp
For 7 inch tablet layout-sw600dp
For 10 inch tablet layout-sw720dp

For your images
For phone drawable-sw320dp
For 7 inch tablet drawable-sw600dp
For 10 inch tablet drawable-sw720dp

For your string,dimen,theme etc
For phone values-sw320dp
For 7 inch tablet values-sw600dp
For 10 inch tablet values-sw720dp
```

Comment: what should be the size of my attached image in pixels for phone ,7 inch tablet and 10 inch tablet.